# Linux FIFO not returning EOF when I expect it to

Tags: python, linux, pipe

Let us consider the following Python code, to be executed by cpython on a Linux system (warning: it will try to create or overwrite files in `/tmp/first`, `/tmp/second` and `/tmp/third`).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import subprocess
import os
import sys
import threading

class ThreadizedPopen(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, command, stdin_name, stdout_name):
        super(ThreadizedPopen, self).__init__()
        self.command = command
        self.stdin_name = stdin_name
        self.stdout_name = stdout_name
        self.returncode = None

    def run(self):
        with open(self.stdin_name, 'rb') as fin:
            with open(self.stdout_name, 'wb') as fout:
                popen = subprocess.Popen(self.command, stdin=fin, stdout=fout, stderr=None)
                popen.communicate()
                self.returncode = popen.returncode

def main():
    os.system('mkfifo /tmp/first')
    os.system('mkfifo /tmp/second')
    os.system('mkfifo /tmp/third')

    popen1 = ThreadizedPopen(['cat'], '/tmp/first', '/tmp/second')
    popen2 = ThreadizedPopen(['cat'], '/tmp/second', '/tmp/third')
    popen1.start()
    popen2.start()
    with open('/tmp/third') as fin:
        print fin.read()
    popen1.join()
    popen2.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I execute it then, on another shell, I write something in `/tmp/first` (say with `echo test > /tmp/first`). I would expect the Python program to quickly exit and print the same thing I fed to the first FIFO.

In theory it should happen that the string I wrote in `/tmp/first` gets copied over by the two `cat` processes spawned by my program to the other two FIFOs and then picked up by the main Python program to be wrote on its stdout. As soon as every `cat` process finished, it should close its end of the writing FIFO, making the corresponding reading end return EOF and triggering the termination of the following `cat` process. Looking at the program with `strace` reveals that the test string is copied correctly through all the three FIFOs and is read by the main Python program. The first FIFO is also correctly closed (and the first `cat` process exits, together with its manager Python thread). However the second `cat` process is stuck in a `read()` call, expecting data from its reading FIFO.

I do not understand why this happens. From the [`pipe(t)` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) (which, I understand, covers also this kind of FIFOs) it seems that a read on a FIFO is returned EOF as soon as the writing end (and all its duplicates) are closed. According to `strace` this appears to be the trace (in particular, the `cat` process is dead, thus all its file descriptors are closed; its managing thread has closed its descriptors as well, I can see it in the `strace` output).

Can you suggest me why that happens? I can post the `strace` output if it can be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27451182/proper-way-to-close-all-files-after-subprocess-popen-and-communicate)
and simply added `close_fds=True` to your `subprocess` call. Your code now reads:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import subprocess
import os
import sys
import threading

class ThreadizedPopen(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, command, stdin_name, stdout_name):
        super(ThreadizedPopen, self).__init__()
        self.command = command
        self.stdin_name = stdin_name
        self.stdout_name = stdout_name
        self.returncode = None

    def run(self):
        with open(self.stdin_name, 'rb') as fin:
            with open(self.stdout_name, 'wb') as fout:
                popen = subprocess.Popen(self.command, stdin=fin, stdout=fout, stderr=None, close_fds=True)
                popen.communicate()
                self.returncode = popen.returncode

def main():
    os.system('mkfifo /tmp/first')
    os.system('mkfifo /tmp/second')
    os.system('mkfifo /tmp/third')

    popen1 = ThreadizedPopen(['cat'], '/tmp/first', '/tmp/second')
    popen2 = ThreadizedPopen(['cat'], '/tmp/second', '/tmp/third')
    popen1.start()
    popen2.start()
    with open('/tmp/third') as fin:
        print fin.read()
    popen1.join()
    popen2.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I placed your code in a script called `fifo_issue.py` and ran it in a terminal. The script was idling as you'd expect (ignore `mkfifo: cannot create fifo`):

```
$ python fifo_issue.py 
mkfifo: cannot create fifo ‘/tmp/first’: File exists
mkfifo: cannot create fifo ‘/tmp/second’: File exists
mkfifo: cannot create fifo ‘/tmp/third’: File exists
```

Then, in a second terminal, I typed:

```
$ echo "I was echoed to /tmp/first!" > /tmp/first
```

Back to the first terminal that's still running your idling threads:

```
$ python fifo_issue.py 
mkfifo: cannot create fifo ‘/tmp/first’: File exists
mkfifo: cannot create fifo ‘/tmp/second’: File exists
mkfifo: cannot create fifo ‘/tmp/third’: File exists
I was echoed to /tmp/first!
```

After which python exited correctly

Comment: Thanks, it works. I do not really understand why my previous code did not work, so I will accept the answer only if in some reasonable time nobody is able to give more insight on what is actually happening.

Comment: @giomasce Yeah, do that. I'm just providing the full, working example for people to copy/paste if they're interested - I'm not adding much information. I should have commented instead, I guess. Anyway, we need a Unix ninja or a very patient doc reader to elaborate on what's going on under the hood.